# Google AdSense went missing

Tags: google-adsense

I bought a new domain and successfully redirected my blogger account. Everything works OK except the Google Ads I previously had on my blogger is now missing after this redirect.

Does it take time for the Ads to reappear? It's been around 12 hours now after the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the obvious variables before you panic. Does this happen in all browsers? It takes advertisers a while to catch up to the latest tweaks in ad-blocking code.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have reported this same problem in the [Google product forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/YqfJRZeppjA).    The suggested solution is to  set up a URL channel for your new domain in your AdSense account.  Google has [instructions for doing so here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/126138?ctx=as2&rd=1).